# how to re-add and re-commit in git command line

Tags: git, github, push, commit

I'm not sure I understand what the command `git commit -am "commit_message"` does. I used it hoping that it would do:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit_message
```

But when I pushed to github, I noticed that the new files (untracked before I called my command) haven't been pushed. After verification, those new files weren't even added with my commit.
So I tried to call `git add .` myself, followed by `git commit -m "commit_message` to solve my problem manually. This didn't seem to work either.

So here is my question, is there a way to add all untracked files to the index at once?

Comment: if you do `git status` which is the output?

Comment: `# On branch vincent`<br>`nothing to commit (working directory clean)`

Comment: What if you try with `git add ./*` and then `git commit -a -m "message"`? In case this does not work, I'll try to replicate your issue and see if I can find a solution

Comment: @mardavi given that `git status` reports that there is nothing to commit and that the working directory is clean, doing an additional `git add` won't solve the problem.

Comment: @ColinHebert, yes I know, but I had no other idea since `git add .` should have worked and a try is not big lost of time. I expect it not to work, that's why I didn't post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify your question with what I could gather from your current problem, if I did it wrong, I apologise, and feel free to revert it.

If I was right, you have to know that `git commit -a -m ""` (it isn't quite `-am`), only adds tracked and modified files to the index, so an untracked file shouldn't be added to the commit, that's the expected behaviour.

Regarding your attempt to call `git add .`, this should have worked as this command adds untracked files, and should work as you expect.

Given the comment you added to your question (on `git status`), it seems that there isn't any untracked file to add. So either you already added those and committed the change, or those files are ignored by git.

This could be caused by a configuration in your `.gitignore` file